# View.invalidate() does not seem to call View.onDraw()

Tags: android, invalidation

I have a drawing library, and with it I have a custom View.  When any updates need to be done, the library calls the view's `invalidate()` method.  And then the `onDraw()` method is called, and everything works just fine.

However, when I add the attribute of `usesSdkVersion="14"` to my `AndroidManifest.xml file`, this stops working.  No longer is my view's `onDraw()` method getting called anymore.

MORE INFO:
It seems that when I call `invalidate()` as the result of a button push in my app, the View updates as expected.  Also, there is one animation inside my library which is working correctly.  So apparently sometimes it is working correctly.  But most of the time, it is not getting redrawn.  Is there any state that a custom View can be in that would cause the OS to skip redrawing it after `invalidate()` is called?

Comment: Are you still calling it from the UI thread? else you must use postInvalidate().

Comment: I tried changing the invalidate to postInvalidate just to check that, and the problem still exists.

Comment: Is hardware acceleration on or off?

Comment: I changed the minSdkVersion to 11, so I could explicitly set the hardwareAccelerated attribute to "false", and the problem still exists.

Comment: ANSWER: So it turns out that I had to call `invalidate()` on another view too.  Didn't have to do this before the change to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Answer (score 6):

From android 3.0, when using Hardware acceleration, the drawing of views is recorded and stored at the GPU.

So when you got two views: A above B, and you call `B.invalidate`, `B.onDraw` will be called and record to the GPU, but `A.onDraw` will not be called because it's already recorded!

This is the different from non-hardware acceleration mode when all the views `onDraw` been called.

Answer (score 2):

by official documents:

However, because hardware acceleration is not supported for all of the 2D drawing operations, turning it on might affect some of your applications that use custom views or drawing calls. Problems usually manifest themselves as invisible elements, exceptions, or wrongly rendered pixels.

To remedy this, Android gives you the option to enable or disable hardware acceleration at the following levels:

**Application**

> ```
> <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>
> ```

**Activity**

> ```
> <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
>   <activity ... />
>   <activity android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />
> </application>
> ```

**Window**

> getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);

**View**

> myView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

I test in my view.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a bug in Android. Instead of *invalidate()* try to use method of the same name with four parameters:

```
view.invalidate(0,0,view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
```

By the way, it is better practice to invalidate only that region, which is changing. Pass left, top, right, bottom coordinates of invalidated region.